# How do I improve my endgame technique?

Tags: endgame, books, recommendations

I have decent endgame technique and recently bought Jesus De La Villa's *100 endgames you must know*. How do I shift it closer to top level endgame technique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I shift it closer to top level endgame technique?

The simple answer is you study the more difficult endgames which normally require IM or GM level playing strength to master. What you should be looking to learn here is:

1. When the endgame is won, how to win for the stronger side
2. When the endgame is won, how to put up the greatest resistance for the weaker side
3. When it is drawn, how to draw
4. When it is drawn, how to win when the weaker side goes wrong

These endgames would include:

1. K+Q vs K+R
2. K+R+B vs K+R
3. K+Q vs K+R+P
4. K+R+f+h vs K+R
5. K+R+a+f+g+h vs K+R+f+g+h

A useful resource is *Fundamental Chess Endings* by Karsten Mueller and Frank Lamprecht.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer to you question is:Now read and master your endgame book!

Without knowing your rating there are some general points to be made; applicable to players of all strengths.

1.Take every opportunity to apply this new knowledge to your own games when ever you play.

2.Self analysis and application of your newly learned endgame technique.Analysis with a mentor or buddy of greater strength is especially valuable.

3.I should point out that you should attempt to make parallel improvements in the other phases of the game :all the endgame instruction in the world is entriely superflous if you loose in the middlegame or opening.

4.Widen your experience by playing many games frequently.

So in summary : Read and master your book  and Applicaction , Analysis , Advice (from a stronger player),Attention ( to the whole game) and Acquire experience by frequent play.